# Any suggestions on data syncronization from a server to a desktop?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, synchronization

I have a web based CRM system that stores all the client data from all the clients into one database (MS Sql Server). We need to build a system that maintains a local copy of the data for each client. So basically the client database will have all tables and columns except for the ClientId that is in ever server table. I am aware that I will need to add fields to the server to support synchronization.

Are there any good solutions or components already out there to help me accomplish this?

We are using MS Sql Server and .NET C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server vs. a local one (express) - this is what MS does in it's CRM.

Sync framework (part of SQL Server etc.) could be helpful to programming a sync mechanism, in case you do not want to use replication here - which MAY work.